# Why use float 16 in histogram equalization

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

Following code is for histogram equalization using opencv and python.In Following Histogram Equalization Why do we use float16 for histogram but in the end we convert it back to int 8 bit.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
path = "fingerprint256by256.pgm"
img = cv2.imread(path,0)

#To display image before equalization
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)


a = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)
b = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)

height,width=img.shape

#finding histogram
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
    g = img[j,i]
    a[g] = a[g]+1

print(a)   


#performing histogram equalization
tmp = 1.0/(height*width)
b = np.zeros((256,),dtype=np.float16)

for i in range(256):
    for j in range(i+1):
        b[i] += a[j] * tmp;
    b[i] = round(b[i] * 255);

# b now contains the equalized histogram
b=b.astype(np.uint8)

print(b)

#Re-map values from equalized histogram into the image
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        g = img[j,I]
        img[j,i]= b[g]

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Maybe to make the calculations with higher precision? Who wrote the code? Did you ask them why they made this choice?

Comment: float16 is an odd choice of type. typical CPUs don't support it yet. it has 10 bits of mantissa. at least use float32. that has 23 bits of mantissa. I would really have used integers, uint32 to be sure.

Comment: source of this broken code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578876/histogram-equalization-using-python-and-opencv-without-using-inbuilt-functions

Comment: Counts for any given bin can be more than 256. So you need a larger bit-depth to store such values.